How to Apply a URL Filter in a Superset Dashboard
I need to provide a filter for an Apache Superset dashboard via URL parameter and apply the filter to the data shown. I can set the filter via URL parameter, but it is not applied to the data in the charts.
I followed the steps in the article Apache Superset — Use URL to filter dashboards. The filter is set correctly in the UI at the top left. But the filter is not automatically applied to the data. I need to manually click "APPLY FILTERS" at the bottom left to actually activate the filter settings I passed on in the URL.
Others seem to have the same problem, see this Github issue. How can I configure Apache Superset so that a filter provided via URL parameter is automatically applied to the data?

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged.

I found the problem. It was sitting before the keyboard. In the URL I was using the wrong value for the <column> parameter. When applying the second "name" tag from the "targets" section as <column> the filtering works as expected, see the JSON METADATA of the dashboard below.
The instructions from the article Apache Superset — Use URL to filter dashboards work exactly as I need it. You construct the URL parameters like this:
native_filters=(NATIVE_FILTER-<id>:(__cache:(label:'<value>',validateStatus:!f,value:!('<value>')),extraFormData:(filters:!((col:<column>,op:IN,val:!('<value>')))),filterState:(label:'<value>',validateStatus:!f,value:!('<value>')),id:NATIVE_FILTER-<id>,ownState:()))
You get <id> = m3qtzHVtH and <column> = planning_group from the JSON METADATA:
    {
      "id": "NATIVE_FILTER-m3qtzHVtH",
      "controlValues": {
        "enableEmptyFilter": false,
        "defaultToFirstItem": false,
        "multiSelect": false,
        "searchAllOptions": true,
        "inverseSelection": false
      },
      "name": "Customer (Planning Group)",
      "filterType": "filter_select",
      "targets": [{"datasetId": 104, "column": {"name": "planning_group"}}],
      "defaultDataMask": {``

